# How to debug corrupted files in ~/.config directory?

Tags: login, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

Due to some hard drive issues my home directory was corrupted and I had to reinstall Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME. I recovered my files from the corrupted partition, but now, when I try to login, it just enters a login loop and, after a short black screen, it just goes back to the login screen.

I have tracked down the problem to the `~/.config` directory (if I rename it, I can login normally).

My current `~/.config` directory:

[image: My current ~/.config]

How can I find the specific files that are causing that error without renaming each of them individually and rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** way to fix this is to rename the `.config` folder to `.config.HOLD`, then log out/in, and let it create a new `.config` folder with the minimum required files, then copy all of the files from `.config.HOLD` folder into the new `.config` folder, skipping duplicates.

```
cp -an ~/.config.HOLD ~/.config
```

Comment: I don't think this would really help because I do want to copy ALL the files (except the corrupted one) but if I do it like you said this could also copy the corrupted one and I still wouldn't know which specific file it was.

Comment: @DominikSchmidt no, doing it my way would copy all the files EXCEPT the corrupted file that is causing the login problem.

Comment: @DominikSchmidt  Something like `cp -an ~/.config.HOLD ~/.config` should work.

Comment: The copy command given should read: `cp -anT ~/.config.HOLD ~/.config` The option `-T` means `--no-target-directory`; treat `DEST` as a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do on unknown errors is looking into the relevant log files to get some hints on what may cause the problems.

For system issues the `syslog` is usually a good place to start:

```
sudo less /var/log/syslog
```